# How to create a generic Complex type in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to create a Complex type to represent complex numbers.

Following works:

```
Prelude> data Complex = Complex Int Int

Prelude> :t Complex
Complex :: Int -> Int -> Complex
```

How can I change this to accept any Num type, instead of just Int.

I tried following:

```
Prelude> data Complex a = Num a => Complex a a
```

but got this:

```
* Data constructor `Complex' has existential type variables, a context, or a specialised result type
    Complex :: forall a. Num a => a -> a -> Complex a
    (Use ExistentialQuantification or GADTs to allow this)
* In the definition of data constructor `Complex'
  In the data type declaration for `Complex'
```

I'm not really sure what to make of this error. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Traditional `data` in Haskell is just that: *data*. It doesn't need to know anything about the properties of its fields, it just needs to be able to *store* them. Hence there's no real need to constrain the fields at that point; just make it

```
data Complex a = Complex !a !a
```

(`!` because strict fields are better for performance).

Of course when you then implement the `Num` instance, you *will* need a constraint:

```
instance (Num a) => Num (Complex a) where
  fromInteger = (`Complex`0) . fromInteger
  Complex r i + Complex ρ ι = Complex (r+ρ) (i+ι)
  ...
```

...in fact, you need the much stronger constraint `RealFloat a` to implement `abs`, at least that's how [the standard version does it](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.Complex.html#line-120). (Which means, `Complex Int` is actually not usable, not with the standard `Num` hierarchy; you need e.g. `Complex Double`.)

That said, it is also possible to bake the constraint in to the data type itself. The ExistentialTypes syntax you tried is highly limiting though and not suitable for this; what you want instead is the [GADT](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT)

```
data Complex a where
   Complex :: Num a => a -> a -> Complex a
```

With that in place, you could then implement e.g. addition without mentioning any constraint in the signature

```
cplxAdd :: Complex a -> Complex a -> Complex a
cplxAdd (Complex r i) (Complex ρ ι) = Complex (r+ρ) (i+ι)
```

You would now need to fulfill `Num` *whenever you try to construct* a `Complex` value though. That means, you'd still need an explicit constraint in the `Num` instance.

Also, this version is potentially much slower, because the `Num` dictionary actually needs to be stored in the runtime representation.

Answer (score 3):

Type constructors cannot be constrained in pure Haskell, only functions can. So it is supposed that you declare

```
data Complex a = Complex a a
```

and then constrain functions, like

```
conjugate :: (Num a) => Complex a -> Complex a
conjugate (Complex x y) = Complex x (-y)
```

In fact, the type and constraint for `conjugate` can be derived by the compiler, so you can just define the implementation:

```
conjugate (Complex x y) = Complex x (-y)
```

However, if you really wish to constrain the type constructor `Complex`, you can turn on some *extensions* that enable it, namely `ExistentialQuantification` or `GADTs`, as the compiler suggests. To do this, add this line to the very beginning of your file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
```

Those are called [pragmas](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html).

Answer (score 2):

While you could, as the compiler message instructs, use `ExistentialQuantification`, you could also define the type like this:

```
data Complex a = Complex a a deriving (Show, Eq)
```

It's a completely unconstrained type, so perhaps another name would be more appropriate... This type seems to often be called `Pair`...

When you write functions, however, you can constrain the values contained in the type:

```
myFunction :: Num a => Complex a -> a
myFunction (Complex x y) = x + y
```